# Show Storage Image On Glide Using FileProvider.getUriFile..()

Tags: java, android, android-glide, android-fileprovider, scoped-storage

Pls I have add the provider permission xml in my androidmanifest.xml , how to show image from File Path in Glide android 11, image showing in Android SDK lower that 11.

```
public Uri getUri(Context context) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", getFile());
    }
```

Glide.with(context).load(status.getUri()).into(holder.thumbnail);

FileProvider xml, scoped Storage requires this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

In my android manifest file I have the following xml tags, my be I'm doing it wrong for android 11

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.oasis.metasaver.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Comment: You do not need `FileProvider` for showing images within your own app. `FileProvider` is for sharing content with other apps.

Comment: Pls how can I use this, I try using File but only displaying on Android 10 below not working on Android 11

Comment: Uri.fromFile(new File("")); Not working on Android 11 with Glide , also Uri.parse(path); not working at all

Comment: Glide supports the new File() passed in Glide...from(new File()) but not working in Android 11 upward

Comment: The implication is that you do not have read access to the image. `FileProvider` does not solve that. Where did you get your `File` from?

Comment: I used new File(dir).listFiles(), I think I know the problem scoped memory on Android 11. I don't know how to implement scoped-storage for glide to read file from the above

Comment: The files are directly from new File("...").listDir() method. But Glide can't read the file showing white blanks on Android 11 , maybe cos of scoped-storage

Comment: I'm creating a status saver so can't use mediastore

Comment: "The files are directly from new File("...").listDir() method" -- what is the value of `...`? "I'm creating a status saver so can't use mediastore" -- I do not know what a "status saver" is, sorry.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/Media/.Statuses that's the value of ``...`` a WhatsApp status Saver

Comment: That content is now private. As far as I know, there is no way for you to access it, except perhaps via `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and you may not have justification to use that permission.

Comment: Thanks I'm coding using scoped data now